# Include scala classes in the sources jar generated by maven package

Tags: scala, maven

The following plugin added to the `pom.xml` allows source-jar to be created when performing `mvn package`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

The usage of the `scala-maven-plugin` is :

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <jvmArgs>
        <jvmArg>-Xmx12g</jvmArg>
      </jvmArgs>
      <args>
        <arg>-feature</arg>
        <arg>-deprecation</arg>
        <arg>-target:jvm-1.7</arg>
      </args>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

However only the `java` sources are being included: the scala sources are left out.  Note that we are using the standard maven directory layout. In particular we have scala sources here:

```
  src/main/scala
```

So - are there additional options to the `maven-source-plugin` to encourage it to invite the scala classes to participate? Or a different scala-specific plugin and/or option to get them onboard?

Comment: Are you using the `scala-maven-plugin`?

Comment: @Tunaki  Compliation is fine - but even so your question is a good one. I have updated the OP.

Comment: Try to add `<goal>add-source</goal>` into the execution of the `scala-maven-plugin`. This should add `src/main/scala` as source folder, so that `maven-source-plugin` can use it.

Comment: @Tunaki  That sounds like what I had been looking for - but could not remember. Will try it and get back.

Comment: @Tunaki  Confirmed that did the trick. Please make it an answer and I will award.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html) goal of the [Maven Source Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) will bundle all of the sources of the Maven project into a JAR. You can select what to include or exclude in those source folders (with the [`includes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html#includes) and [`excludes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html#excludes) parameters), but you cannot add whole new source folders to it; they must be added as source folders of the Maven project itself.

When you have a [pure Scala project](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/usage.html), `src/main/scala` and `src/test/scala` are declared as source folders, because you would have:

```
<sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
```

in your POM, overriding the default `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`. So the Maven Source Plugin would correctly add the sources present in those two folders without additional configuration.

But when you have a [mixed Java / Scala project](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html), the `<sourceDirectory>` and `<testSourceDirectory>` element are typically left in to their default values. This does not create any problems with regard to compiling or running Scala code with the plugin, as it looks up the files by default in [`${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../scala`](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#sourceDir). However, other unrelated Maven plugins can't know about those new folders.

To fix this, the plugin provides the [`add-source`](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html) goal, which adds `src/main/scala` and `src/test/scala` as source and test source directory to the Maven project, and, thus, makes them available for the other plugins relying on the source directories, like the Maven Source Plugin. You should therefore change your POM to:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-source</goal>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <!-- rest of configuration -->
</plugin>
```

Comment: oh! I know what happened . The sources-jar *contained only **JAVA** classes*. So it *was* included - but had no effect (afa scala classes sources).  I am trying to figure out how to fix the *scala-maven* plugin to resolve. In any case - **your** tip here is working fine: the (mostly empty) jar file **is** included!

Comment: @javadba I'm not sure I understand, the sources JAR does not only contain the `.java` source files, it also contains the `.scala` source files. But yes, it will not contain the compiled `.class`.

Comment: It is *supposed* to include both java and scala source files but does not. That is a different issue that I'm addressing to user of the `scala-maven` plugin.

Comment: @javadba You may have another issue with the configuration then, because, as I commented before, using the sample POM in this answer and the `maven-source-plugin` configuration from the question, running `mvn clean package` does produce a `-sources.jar` which contains `.java` and `.scala` source files. It also apparently [worked for you before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553948/include-scala-classes-in-the-sources-jar-generated-by-maven-package/40554572?noredirect=1#comment68347049_40553948), so maybe something changed in-between?